# How do I export using Cloud SQL API from Cloud SQL instances owned by another project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api-php-client, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to export a table from a Cloud SQL database owned by another project. The calling project has access and can successfully list instances (using getItems()), but it when I try to export is returns "The client is not authorized to make this request."

Here is the code that I am using to export.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuth(new Google_Auth_AppIdentity($client));
$client->getAuth()>authenticateForScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin');
$client->getAuth()>authenticateForScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform');
$sqladmin = new Google_Service_SQLAdmin($client);
$postBody = new Google_Service_SQLAdmin_InstancesExportRequest();

//Set csv options
$csv_options = new Google_Service_SQLAdmin_ExportContextCsvExportOptions();
$csv_options->setSelectQuery('SELECT id FROM test.test;');

//set export context options.
$ec = new Google_Service_SQLAdmin_ExportContext();
$ec->setCsvExportOptions($csv_options);

$ec->setUri('gs://bucket/file.csv');

$postBody->setExportContext($ec);

$response = $sqladmin->instances->export('testing-project-xxxx', 'database', $postBody);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$response = $sqladmin->instances->export('testing-project-xxxx', 'database', $postBody);
```

**Replace database name with instance name**